# How to remove .php and .html to URLs and add trailing slash in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a landing page that includes a faq.html page and a where-to-buy.php page. I'd like remove the .html/.php from the end of the URLs and add a trailing slash for all URLs. So:

www.website.com/faq.html -> www.website.com/faq/

www.website.com/where-to-buy.php -> www.website.com/where-to-buy/

How can I do this in Nginx? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

That's a bit of a complicated question, there are lots of ways to make that happen, the simplest of which is to convert all the files into index files.

Assuming your directory structure looks like this,

www/faq.html

www/where-to-buy.php

you could change it to

www/faq/index.html

www/where-to-buy/index.php

and that would solve the problem ... however that might not be the best answer, it would depend on how you are building this, and how you want to maintain it in the future